# How to display a short description about a Post in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I get Post using Wp_query(). And then show post_thumbnail and the title.

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'type' => 'post',
    'category__in' => '23',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'offset' => 2,
);

$lastBlog = new WP_Query($args);
if ($lastBlog->have_posts()):
    while ($lastBlog->have_posts()): $lastBlog->the_post();

        if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
            the_post_thumbnail();
            the_title(sprintf('<h4 class="entry-title"><a href="%s">', esc_url(get_permalink())), '</a></h4>');
        }

    endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

If I want to show short description about the post under the Title and insert Read More, how can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways you could do that. One way is to just output the content of the article, and put a 'Read more' tag in the text `<!--more-->`, and you'll get the text outputted with the 'Read more' button after it:

```
<?php 
$args = array( 
    'type' => 'post',
    'category__in' => '23',
    'posts_per_page' => 1, 
    'offset' => 2,
    );

$lastBlog = new WP_Query( $args ); 

if( $lastBlog->have_posts() ):
    while( $lastBlog->have_posts() ): $lastBlog->the_post();
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {  
    echo '<div class="post_wrapper">';
    the_post_thumbnail();
    the_title( sprintf('<h4 class="entry-title"><a href="%s">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ),'</a></h4>' );
    the_content( 'Read more ...' );
    echo '</div>';
        }
    endwhile;
endif;

wp_reset_postdata();      
?>
```

I've wrapped everything in `.post_wrapper` div, for easier handling.

The other way is to use `the excerpt()` with a manually added 'Read more' button

```
<?php 
$args = array( 
    'type' => 'post',
    'category__in' => '23',
    'posts_per_page' => 1, 
    'offset' => 2,
    );

$lastBlog = new WP_Query( $args ); 

if( $lastBlog->have_posts() ):
    while( $lastBlog->have_posts() ): $lastBlog->the_post();
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {  
    echo '<div class="post_wrapper">';
    the_post_thumbnail();
    the_title( sprintf('<h4 class="entry-title"><a href="%s">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ),'</a></h4>' );
    the_excerpt();
    echo '<a href="'.esc_url(get_permalink()).'" class="read_more_button" title="'.esc_html__('Read more...', 'theme_slug').'">'.esc_html__('Read more...', 'theme_slug').'</a>';
    echo '</div>';
        }
    endwhile;
endif;

wp_reset_postdata();      
?>
```

You can choose which one to use.

Also are you sure you don't want to display the post if you don't have the thumbnail? if not, just move the if condition before the title, and you should have the post, even if you didn't set the post thumbnail. If you meant it this way, then all is ok. :D